# Smarty Variables not Changing from inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables, smarty

I have a smarty variable assigned to false. Then within Javascript I will be running a function to return whether that smarty variable should change to true or stay false. At the moment I'm always getting the `else` portion of the js `if` statement.

This is a very simple example, but it gets the point across... If the random number generated is `1` change the smarty variable to true otherwise keep it at false.

```
{assign var= "testB" value= false }

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
{literal}
   let randNum = Math.round(Math.random());
   if(randNum == 1){
      {/literal} "{$testB = true}" {literal}
   } else {
      {/literal} "{$testB = false}" {literal}
   }
   console.log( randNum );
   console.log( {/literal} "{$testB}" {literal} );
{/literal}
</script>
```

What am I missing? Its been a long day so it may be something really obvious Im missing :-)

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

If I run `console.log()` inside the if statements he shows me that it iterates through the if statement correctly, but the smarty variable will always change to false, or whatever I set it to inside the `{else}`.

```
let randNum = Math.round(Math.random());
if(randNum == 1){
  {/literal} "{$testB = true}" {literal}
  console.log('here');
} else {
  {/literal} "{$testB = false}" {literal}
  console.log('here2');
}
```

So with the above code, if `randNum` is 1 it will console log 'here', but the smarty variable will be false - or whatever I set it to inside the `{else}`.

Comment: I haven't touched smarty in years, but shouldn't it simply be `"{$testB = true}"` to change the value of a variable?

Comment: You would be correct lol. I just copied the code over incorrectly. I will fix the above. But it still remains the same issue. It is not converting the smarty var to `true` if the random number is 1.

Comment: Your problem is that smarty is executed before javascript, so you cannot mix both that way. Either use the smarty conditions, or assign the value of your smarty variable to a javascript variable and act on that (depending on what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: @Swal can elaborate on the “assign the value of your smarty variable to a JavaScript variable” part... not understanding this. Thank you Sir!!!

Comment: @Skwal My intentions for this is to create a kind of A/B testing. JS will randomly generate either a `1` or a `0` and will assign the smarty variable accordingly. Then after this executes, I have a Smarty if statement `{if $testB == true}` show this page `{else}` show that page. This is a simple example but the feature we will be integrating relies on js to do this and I was hoping a simple setup like this would get us going. Was really hoping to avoid actual php, but its looking like I can't avoid it. Any other ideas. Thank you!!!!!